# tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: not being called when delegate is set

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I think I've done my homework here.

I want my app delegate to be the delegate for my `UITabBarController`.

Using IB, I've connected `UITabBarController`'s delegate to my Application Delegate.

App Delegate Header file is:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
```

The delegate method I'm trying to implement is:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"shouldSelectViewController called.");
    // do some stuff with viewController
    return YES;
}
```

My app delegate has an outlet to the `UITabBarController` that's connected in IB.  When I do this:

```
NSLog(@"tab bar controller delegate is %@", self.tabBarController.delegate);
```

I get a good result such as `tab bar controller delegate is <MyAppDelegate: 0x6e86a30>`.

What am I missing?

Comment: One thing i'd like to say,The tab bar controller calls this(shouldSelectViewController) method in response to the user tapping a tab bar item.just Click on any TabBar Item For Checking that method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  And yes, that's what I'm doing.  The method is still not being called, however.

Comment: i am trying your code as you give it works for me

Comment: @galacticfury check your delegate Connection in window.

Comment: My delegate connection in IB appears to be correct.  I'm really baffled because my setup is, as far as I can tell, identical to the example Apple project, Tabster.  Tabster also uses a UITabBarController delegate method, and it's being called.  But mine is not.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.  I had some old code in my `RootViewController` that set up this controller as the delegate.  No delegate methods were implemented on the `RootViewController`, so it appeared as if nothing was happening.  Because the `RootViewController` is set as delegate AFTER `MyAppDelegate`, the delegate was actually set to the `RootViewController`.

So the lesson is double-check your code to make sure some other object isn't also being set as the delegate.

Comment: Wow! Same here. I still can't believe that this was my problem...Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Just write this code. Usually in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

If the current controller is a `UITabBarController` then:

```
self.delegate = self
```